# During installing of apache superset, while "superset db upgrade"

Tags: apache-superset

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\ACER\Virtual_environment\venv\Scripts\superset.exe_*main**.py", line 4, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'superset'

Answer (score 0):

The virtual environment you are using to run `"superset db upgrade"` has no superset installation. Confirm you are running the right virtual environment